# Steps to switching the AdMob account in order to change country

Tags: android, admob, firebase-admob

I know the question of changing the AdMob Country or Currency is been around many years. All they suggest is closing the current AdMob account and open a new one. But I did not find any step by step tutorial on how to do it.

1. If I close my current AdMob account and open a new one, I will lose the revenue during the process? OR should I open a new AdMob account and configure the new new AD ids in the app while my current AdMob account is open? Is there any risk to be suspended by Google as I will have two AdMob accounts open until I deploy the new versions of my apps with new AdMob and then shutdown the old AdMob?
2. When we transfer the Google Play apps from one account to another, will it transfer the AdMob apps & Ids to?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So how did the transition go ?

Comment: I guess there's no solution to this issue. I'm in the same dilemma, my account was created in UAE and currently I'm in Canada. My last payment was issued through Westren Union, when I was there to receive the money sent by google, they said that you can not withdraw this money from here, you have to go to UAE to get this money or ask the sender to change the recipient country to Canada. @KhalidHex do you know any solution to this issue? Is there any possibility I can withdraw my earnings from Canada?

Comment: I found some obscure support page on some blog but i didn't tried it still .... they said you need to make a request here and attach all necessary documents https://support.google.com/adsense/contact/change_country_new2 ... check it and let me know what happened .

Comment: That one says it's for adsense... has anyone tried and see if it works for admob?

Answer (score 0):

The change of country form for Adsense can be found via this link [Change the payment address in your AdSense account](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2628816?hl=en).

Please sign in with your Google account before clicking the link. Otherwise, the country change form link does not appear.

I have also attached the page screenshot.

[Change of country form screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2io3.png)

Note: Last month I switched my AdMob account country by following these steps. Adsense instructions are also valid for Admob.

Comment: Hi This is for the AdMob. Your answer is about AdSense.

Comment: Hi @Sam, according to Google official resources AdMob relies on AdSense and, an AdSense account is required to use AdMob. Probably you already have an AdSense account as well which is linked to your AdMob account. So, I assume you can follow AdSense instructions. For resources please check these links; [Get started AdSense](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3015168?hl=en), [How does AdMob use AdSense & Google Ads?](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7356173?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the country associated with your AdMob account. The only way to change your country is to delete your account and start a new one.
If you want to switch to another currency, you'll need to close your current account and open a new one.